# pandas numeric value showing up in non numeric Serie

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

Why are numeric values seen as non numeric even after str.strip has been called?

This is my situation:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.strip()
id = df['ID']
indices = [ i for (i, v) in enumerate(id.str.isnumeric()) if v == False ]
non_numeric = id.filter(indices)
id.head(-5)

And this is the output of id.head(-5):
141       C536379
154       C536383
235       C536391
236       C536391
237       C536391
           ...   
470612     576618
470614     576618
470616     576618
470618     576618
470673     576618
Name: ID, Length: 7892, dtype: object
```

**Why all those numbers not starting with a letter still in the non_numeric array?**

At first I thought it was due to the leading whitespace, but then I added strip() and nothing has changed.

EDIT: I need to analyse the non numeric values in the Series, so I'm trying to extracting them.

Comment: because `str.strip` only strips white spaces? This looks like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You still need to convert the dataframe column to your desired format. Even, if I have all numbers, I can still make a column of string data type. Pandas doesn't automatically change the data type of a column unless you explicitly tell it to (except for reading in data, where pandas will automatically detect data types). Also, you have strings in your column with the ltters `C`, so it's not possible to convert to a numeric data type like int or float.

Comment: exactly, so there are no whitespaces in front or in the end of 576618. Why has it ended up in the non numeric Serie?

Comment: @DavidErickson I don't need the conversion of the original dataframe, I need to see what are the values that didn't made pandas infer a numeric value for the Serie. So I filter out the non numeric ones to analyse them and surprise! There are numeric values in the non numeric Serie

Comment: Cannot reproduce making a Series with `['C536379', 'C536383', 'C536391', C536391', 'C536391', '576618', '576618', '576618', '576618', '576618']` - The comprehension identifies the numeric items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your latest edit, I believe this is what you are trying to do:

> "EDIT: I need to analyse the non numeric values in the Series, so I'm trying to extracting them."

To look at strings only, there are many ways. Here is one. Use `pd.to_numeric()` to create a series `s` and pass `errors='coerce'`. That will return `NaN` values for data that is not numeric. From there pass that as a filter to your dataframe for the `NaN` rows of that series using `isnull()`:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce')
df = df[s.isnull()]
df

    ID
141 C536379
154 C536383
235 C536391
236 C536391
237 C536391
```